# How do I copy multiple files by wildcard?

Tags: bash, wildcards, file-copy

I have a folder with a number of files in it ABC.* (there are roughly 100 such files). I want to duplicate them all to new files with names starting with DEF.*

So, I want

```
ABC.Page1
ABC.Page2
ABC.Topic12
...etc
```

copied to

```
DEF.Page1
DEF.Page2
DEF.Topic12
...etc
```

What is the simplest way to do this with a batch command (in BASH or similar)? I am thinking something involving sed or awk or xargs, but I'm having difficulty figuring out the syntax.  I could write a Python script, but I'm thinking there is probably a command line solution that is not too complicated.

Comment: A venerable `mc` file manager has a most extensive support for this sort of mass renames.

Comment: @oakad `tar` is no spring-chicken, either. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

How about something like this in bash:

```
for file in ABC.*; do cp "$file" "${file/ABC/DEF}";done
```

you can test it by putting echo in front of the cp command:

```
for file in ABC.*; do echo cp "$file" "${file/ABC/DEF}";done
```

Answer (score 8):

To do this efficiently with a large number of files, it is better to avoid a starting a different `cp` process for each one. One way would be to copy then rename them using `prename` (`rename` is symlinked to this by default on Debian based distros). Using this and the Linux `mktemp`:

```
tmp=$(mktemp -d --tmpdir=.)
cp ABC.* "$tmp"
prename "s:$tmp/ABC:DEF:" "$tmp/"*
rmdir "$tmp"
```

#### Update

Actually `pax` may be a better way to go here:

```
pax -rws '/^ABC/DEF/' ABC.* .
```

Unfortunately, despite `pax` being both POSIX and Linux Standard Base, few distros currently include it by default.

Comment: nice touch using the : as the separator to avoid escaping.

Answer (score 5):

`tar` will do this for you really fast.

#### TEST

First I created 2 directories and 10 files:

```
% mkdir test1 test2 ; cd test1
% for n in `seq 1 10` ; do touch ABC.file$n ; done
% ls

> ABC.file1   ABC.file2  ABC.file4  ABC.file6  ABC.file8
> ABC.file10  ABC.file3  ABC.file5  ABC.file7  ABC.file9
```

Then I copied them:

```
% tar -cf - ./* |\ 
    tar -C../test2 --transform='s/ABC/DEF/' -xf -
% ls ../test2

> DEF.file1   DEF.file2  DEF.file4  DEF.file6  DEF.file8
> DEF.file10  DEF.file3  DEF.file5  DEF.file7  DEF.file9
```

#### TRANSFORM

So GNU `tar` will accept a `sed --transform=EXPRESSION` for file renaming. This can even rename only some of the files. For instance:

```
% tar -cf - ./* |\ 
    tar -C../test2 --transform='s/ABC\(.*[0-5]\)/DEF\1/' -xf -
% ls ../test2

> ABC.file6  ABC.file8  DEF.file1   DEF.file2  DEF.file4
> ABC.file7  ABC.file9  DEF.file10  DEF.file3  DEF.file5
```

So that's one advantage.

#### STREAM

Also consider that this is only two `tar` processes - and that will not alter regardless of your file count.

```
tar | tar
```

`tar` is as optimized as you could want it to be. This will never have problem argument counts or runaway child processes. This is just **A > B** done.

#### ARGUMENTS

I use 7 distinct arguments combined between my two `tar` processes here. The most important one is listed here first:

> **`-` stdout/stdin** - this informs `tar` that it will be streaming either its input or output to or from **`stdin/stdout`** which it will interpret correctly depending on whether or not it is building or extracting an archive.
>
> **`-c` create** - this tells `tar` to build the archive. The next argument `tar` expects is...
>
> **`-f` file** - we specify that `tar` will be working with a `file` object rather than a tape-device or whatever. And the file it will be working with, as noted above, is **`stdin/stdout`** - in other words, our **`|pipe`.**
>
> **`./*` all $PWD/files** - not too much to explain here except that the archive argument comes first, so `-` then `./*`.

...and on the other side of the `|pipe`...

> **`-C` change directory** - this informs `tar` that it needs to change to the directory I specify before performing any other action, so effectively it just `cd ../test2` before extraction.
>
> **`--transform='s/ed/EXPR/'`** - as has already been mentioned, this did the renaming. But the docs indicate that it can take any `sed` expression or `//flag`.
>
> **`-x` extract** - after `tar` changes to our target directory and receives our renaming instructions we instruct it to begin extracting all of the files into its current directory from the `-f - |pipe` archive file. No mystery.

Comment: Here is the `pax` solution for this question. I would add it to my answer, but I think it is better suited here - `pax -rws '/^ABC/DEF/' ABC.* .`

Comment: @Graeme - woah - that's way better! Man, it beats the hell out of pearl rename, too! You should put this in your answer - `pax` is POSIX specified - hence the `pax`.

Comment: `pax` might be POSIX, but it is rarely installed by default unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a less standard tool, I recommend using [mmv](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/mmv.html) (mass move) which was written for this very kind of tasks. Using `mcp` (mass copy), which is part of the suite, you could simply do

```
mcp "ABC.*" "DEF.#1"
```

It's not exactly easy to find download packages. The current Debian package (which Arch also uses in AUR) to compile at home can be found [here](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mmv/mmv_1.01b.orig.tar.gz).

Comment: installs on ubuntu 15.10 out of the box, `apt-get install mmv`

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, put the following lines in your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zmv='noglob zmv'
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

Then, on the command line, [you can run](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv)

```
zcp 'ABC(.*)' 'DEF$1'
```

or simply

```
zcp -W ABC.* DEF.*
```

In another shell, as long as you have zsh installed:

```
zsh -c 'autoload zmv; noglob zmv -CW ABC.* DEF.*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
for i in ABC.*; do cp {ABC,DEF}."${i#*.}"; done
```

Comment: How should I read the `"${i#*.}"` bit?